# How can I convert a concrete directory path to NSURL?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I'd like to know how could I create a URL from a path String.
Here my code:

```
    let completePath = "/Volumes/MyNetworkFolder/"

    do {
        let items = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: completePath)

        for item in items {
            if item.hasDirectoryPath { //String has no member hasDirectoryPath
                itemList.append(item)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to read dir")
        let buttonPushed = dialogOKCancel(question: "Failed to read dir", text: "Map the network folder")
        if(buttonPushed) {
            exit(0)
        }
    }
```

I'd like to add only folders to the itemList array. The hasDirectoryPath is an URL method.
How could i change my code to get URLs not String.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: No need to convert. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410452-attributesofitem tells you if this is a directory. But as MartinR says, you are better off starting with a URL from the outset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use the [`contentsOfDirectory(at url: URL, ...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413768-contentsofdirectory) method of
`FileManager`, that gives you an array of `URL`s instead of
strings:

```
let dirPath = "/Volumes/MyNetworkFolder/"
let dirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath)

do {
    let items = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: dirURL,
                                                            includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    for item in items {
        if item.hasDirectoryPath {
            // item is a URL
            // item.path is its file path as a String
            // ...
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Failed to read dir:", error.localizedDescription)
}
```